# can`t redirect to public resource online htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have downloaded my site and put it local without the uploads folder. All the resource from public_html/uploads is online (a lot of stuff) and i want to make an htaccess to redirect to online uploads.

I created in my project local an empty folder uploads and inside an .htaccess file with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /uploads/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /uploads/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteRule ^((?!uploads/).*)$ uploads/$1 [L,NC]
```

But a can`t get the resource: net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

How can i redirect the local site to take all the resource files from online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need this rule in local `uploads/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^ http://mainsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: it does not trows errors, but the images are not loaded.....when inspect the image url is stil the localhost url for it (it does not grab from exterior)

Comment: What is your exact image URL? Test from a new browser

Comment: the url for the image should be: https://www.mainsite.com/uploads/companies/1251/data/picture-name.jpg
and for localhost: http://www.mainsite.local/assets/img/no-photo.jpg because that image is not found in uploads and that is why is set for no-photo.jpg

Comment: This .htaccess must goto `/uploads/.htaccess` on `mainsite.local` and you must enter this URL in a browser `mainsite.local/uploads/companies/1251/data/picture-name.jpg` **after totally clearing browser cache**

Comment: the htaccess is good if try to load an individual image from localhost.....but i think i know what the problem is. When i load the image i use in php `base_url('uploads/...`) and that base_url in config is set to localhost base_url

Comment: Don't think rewrite rules can fix that problem.

Comment: unfortunately no....beacause the image from uploads content is forced to be read from base_url/uploads....... i`ll search for another solution. Thx anyway ;)